# How to make File Sharing works on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-sharing

I can't make file sharing works on my home PCs.

The situation - I have 2 computers:

- Both with Win10 Home x64.
- In the same WORKGROUP.
- Have different accounts (MS accounts, login using a PIN).
- Have the same sharing settings (see screenshots below).
- On the same router.
- Can ping each other. (we can play games via LAN).

But we can't share a folder. I was looking for a solution for a long time. Nothing helped so far.

Access for everyone:
[image]

Actual issue:
[image]

***Settings:***

...

[image]

...

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local user from the control panel, same user in both PCs, and share a folder with that user.
You can access from the other PC with your actual account using credentials of the local user recently created.
Make sure to log in once in each PC with that local account to make things work afterwards.

Added for clarification: When in a Workgroup, if the account does not exist locally in both computers only a shared folder with "All users" will work without having it, and if you're using microsoft accounts for logging in that "All users" options will not work at all.
Use the "Add network location" way to map a remote folder to force Windows to ask you for credentials.

Comment: Windows don't ask for any password when I'm trying to open a folder. If it would be a thing - I just know passwords for both PC.

Comment: That's because they're not local accounts, neither a folder shared with a local account.

Comment: How 3rd account can solve the problem? Honestly, I don't understand.

Comment: Can turning all accounts into local accounts solve the issue?

Comment: The problem is, indeed, a microsoft accounts vs local accounts issue. But I don't suggest you to turn your accounts to local, as this can arise more configuration problems that you can easily avoid by using a third local account just for this. It's easier, faster, and hassle free.

Comment: What if I need to create another folder? And then another one? Should I login to this local account each time? I can't believe this is the only way.